# Google Glass: How to customize appearance of Home Screen and Menu Items on Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Are you able to customize the appearance at all on the first two screens of Google Glass?
1) The Home screen card with time and "ok glass".
2) The Menu Item card with "ok glass," and a list of available voice actions.

For example, add an image, background image, remove the time, or add additional text. Or maybe put a custom view we create in front of everything.

I'm not looking to change the functionality, just the look and feel.

If not, are there any plans to allow this in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change any of those screens. And I don't believe they will add the ability in the future. But we never know with Google, maybe in the future.

You can always make a feature request here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/